# Redirect user to OneLogin connected/ SSO enabled application from my web application

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, google-workspace, onelogin

I have a OneLogin account and have set up Google Worspace (G Suite) and enabled SSO.

I want the users of my web application to directly get redirected to Google Workspace on clicking a button/link on my application.

Can someone please guide me on this?

I have enabled SSO on OneLogin for Google Workspace and have provisioned my users. Their accounts have been created on Google Workspace but I am not sure how do I make my users jump from my application to Google workspace.